# Contract [Contract's name] not found on network ID: 5777

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, drizzle, factory

I am using truffle with drizzle.

In the contract folder I provide a file that includes two contracts
A that is a factory contract and
B that is created through one of A's functions

After compiling and migrating, I get two contract files as json: 
A.json, B.json

The factory contract gets deployed, however when I run my client, 
I can see in the following error in the console:

```
Contract B not found on network ID: 5777
```

and

```
index.js:1375 uncaught at _callee at _callee 
 at contractsSaga 
 at takeEvery 
 at addContract 
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'contractName' of undefined
```

When inspecting B.json I see that ABI is provided and  contract name
is specified in the file.

Question:
Should B get deployed to be accessible and if so, how to proceed when I want only A to be able to deploy B and only if a certain function is called? Not mentioning A can deploy multiple Bs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found my mistake. 
I made false assumption that the B contract must be passed in drizzle options like so:

```
const options = {
  contracts: [A, B],
  web3: {
    fallback: {
      type: "ws",
      url: "ws://127.0.0.1:9545",
    },
  },
};
```

Since A contains B, there is no need to specify B in contracts, hence the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'B' of undefined
```

Because A contains B (A is a factory for B) options should be like so:

```
const options = {
  contracts: [A],
  web3: {
    fallback: {
      type: "ws",
      url: "ws://127.0.0.1:9545",
    },
  },
};
```